# Why DMSO is used as a control?

Tags: pharmacology, experimental

Coming from a non-biology background, I've realised many academic papers on experiments use DMSO as like a control. This is an example:

> [KN-93, a specific inhibitor of CaMKII inhibits human hepatic stellate cell proliferation in vitro](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4146932/)

What make DMSO so special that so many scientists use it for their experiment and report their results? Why do we need it in the first place?

Comment: Its likely used as a control when its also being used as a solvent, not everything can be done in water

Comment: @zacdav Make your comment an answer, because that's the answer to the question.

Comment: Note that this is often described as a vehicle control. Essentially you are controlling for the effect of the solvent (ie the vehicle) used to introduce the compound of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DMSO can be used as a [solvent for a range of experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_sulfoxide#Applications). In these cases it makes sense to use the solvent as the control.